# Cant' serv static css file with Django, Heroku and whiteNoice

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, django-settings, static-files

I'm trying to serv static files with Django and Heroku. Right now there is only a single .css file.

I followed the Heroku example settings, but it doesn't work. I'm in production, so DEBUG is set to False and I'm trying to use whitenoise.

If I comment out this line in my settings.py (please find the whole thing below):

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

The page is loaded bug no css is loaded.

If it's not commented out I get a 500 error :

```
raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'styles.css'
```

Statics are in a folder named static in the same folder as settings.py

index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
```

settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
SECRET_KEY = 'my_secret'
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myapp.herokuapp.com']
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'my_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_app.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG,
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_app.wsgi.application'
DATABASE_NAME = 'my_app/db.sqlite3'
DATABASES = {...}
validators
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [...]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ="/accounts/login/"
APPEND_SLASH = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 3600
LOGGING = {...}
```

Any help is most appreciated! 
Best regards Kresten

Comment: What is STATIC_ROOT set to? Why is your static file inside the folder with settings, instead of directly inside the project folder? And, although it is not related to your problem, note that you cannot use sqlite with Heroku and this will not work.

Comment: STATIC_ROOT is set to os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles') and BASE_DIR is set to os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
as discribed by https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
The static folder was in the project folde, but it didn't seam to make any difference. I have not come so far yet to handle the database.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask about STATICFILES_DIRS. And you didn't answer why the static directory is in that folder.

Comment: I didn't set STATICFILES_DIRS. I'll try. I don't know why the static directory is there. I've tried anything I could come up with. Can you tell me where it should be? Would collectstatics not find it anyhow?

Comment: No because it is not in an app dir or in a place included in STATICFILES_DIRS. Move it up a level and add that directory into that setting.

Comment: Well you need to start from BASE_DIR, surely.

Comment: I have set STATICFILES_DIRS = (
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
            ), but no change